# In a tool for a programmatic drawing let us capture a locator position into a clipboard

Tags: locator, drawing, clipboard

This code allows one to fast draw a technical sketch. I simplified it to extreme. It contains a disk (instead of your real sketch) and a line pointing to a place in the sketch, which you want to indicate with the marker "12". 
The position where to point and where to place the marker you choose manually using locators:

```
    DynamicModule[{p1 = {0.5, 0.3}, p2 = {0.3, 0.5}},
 Column[{

   LocatorPane[
    Dynamic[{p1, p2}],
    Show[{
      Graphics[{GrayLevel[0.5], Disk[]}],
      Graphics[Dynamic[Line[{p1, p2}]]],
      Graphics[ Dynamic[Text[Style["12", 14], p2]]]
      }, ImageSize -> 300]
                          ],

   Button["Pick up", Column[{Print[p1], Print[p2]}]]
   }]
 ]
```

That' s what you see

[image]

As soon as you have chosen the locators positions, you press the button and coordinates of the locators appear below the sketch. These may be copy-pasted instead of p1 and p2 into the sketch code. Then you copy-paste the Show part with inserted p1 and p2 into another cell:

```
Show[{
  Graphics[{GrayLevel[0.5], Disk[]}],
  Graphics[Dynamic[Line[{{0.269, -0.216}, {1.042, 0.518`}}]]],
  Graphics[ Dynamic[Text[Style["12", 14], {1.042, 0.518`}]]]
  }, ImageSize -> 300]
```

Done: you get your sketch:

[image]

Now it is clear, what I am after. I do not want to copy-paste the chosen p1 and p2. The more that here I simplified the sketch to extreme, while in real cases one might need to do that several tens times. I would prefer to directly press the button and get p1 in a clipboard, press another one and get p2 there.

The question: provided there is a number appeared in your program that you need to copy-paste somewhere. How to programmatically capture this number into the clipboard?

This question appears to be more general than only the one to apply to the drawing tool described above.

Any idea?

Comment: Well, there is `CopyToClipboard` function but maybe you would like to whole Graphics to be printed below?

Comment: @ Kuba Thank you, to print a cell is a good idea in a different situation, but not in my case. Imagine doing a complex sketch with many elements, and using locators to accelerate choosing positions for the markers, arrows and such like secondary sketch elements. In the course of drawing you place them, then change the placement, then change once more, unless your are satisfied. It is necessary to be able to copy-paste just the locator coordinates. In contrast your suggestion  to use `CopyToClipboard` works fine. Why do not you write this comment as a regular answer?

Comment: @Kuba You are right, and it is clearly my illiteracy that I did not do that myself. However, the whole story might be considered as a broader thing, say, in the context of useful tools for programmatic drawing. Actually, I already use your suggestion while drawing.

Comment: Then you'd have to reformulate the question.

Comment: @Kuba  OK, I reformulated it.

Comment: But the question is still the same, so the answer remains `CopyToClipboard`, right?

Comment: @Kuba Well, with its use the code may be changed to achieve the goal.